# CSS class equivalent for LaTeX

Tags: css, latex

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to apply the CSS methodology to the LaTeX template I am building. What I would like to do is to have a set of *classes* that apply a specific style treatment to the bracketed words. For example:

If I have three paragraphs of text, I want to have all of the paragraphs have [0.5cm] of spacing after the last line without having to add `\\[0.5cm]` after each paragraph.

Is there a LaTeX equivalent of defining the treatment for all paragraphs in the preamble so that it cascades throughout my document? The equivalent of:

```
<style> p {padding-bottom:0.5cm} </style>
```

I want to be able to specify multiple version of these *CSS-like LaTeX classes* throughout my document, so I don't need a specific solution. I need help understanding how to add custom labels/names/classes to the preamble and an example of how to use them in the document itself.

Thanks!

Ryan

Comment: You can also try http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you want to define your own environment. Below is an example from [LaTeX wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Customizing_LaTeX#New_Environments).

Put this in your preamble:

```
\newenvironment{king}
{\rule{1ex}{1ex}\hspace{\stretch{1}}}
{\hspace{\stretch{1}}\rule{1ex}{1ex}}
```

And then use the style in the document:

```
\begin{king}
My humble subjects \ldots
\end{king}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could adjust the value of `\parskip`, see [here](http://www.ipp.mpg.de/~dpc/LaTeX/parskip.html) for explanation.

```
\addtolength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
```

Alternatively, you could just use `\setlength`:

```
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5cm}
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem of creating classes in the header, though it does address the example quite nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You could create commands that change the environment (like setting parskip), and issue the commands at different points in the document. Experiment with {bracketing} to change the scope of the changes the command makes.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, it isn't possible. :(

The tutorials [here](http://www.andy-roberts.net/misc/latex/) may be useful though.

Comment: tex is turing complete there is no impossible when you can rewrite the code on the fly